# Getting error when using default task in gulp, shows the following error in Gitbash : Task requires a name that is string

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, git-bash

When I run the command 'gulp' in gitbash this error is displayed for the last line of the code:
throw new Error('Task requires a name that is a string');

Error: Task requires a name that is a string

```
"use strict";
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');  // Runs a local dev server
var open = require('gulp-open');    // Open a URL in a web browser
var config = {
port: 9005,
devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
paths: {
    html:  './src/*.html',
    dist: './dist'
}

};

gulp.task(connect, function(){  
connect.server({
    root: '[dist]',
    port: config.port,
    base: config.devBaseUrl,
    livereload: true
});
});

gulp.task(open,['connect'], function(){ 
gulp.src('dist/index.html')
    .pipe(open({ url:config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/'}));
});

gulp.task(html,function(){      
gulp.src(config.paths.html)
    .pipe(gulp.src(config.paths.dist))  
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'open', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining task first argument should be string.

```
gulp.task('connect', function () {
.....
})
```

This is corrected file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');  // Runs a local dev server
var open = require('gulp-open');    // Open a URL in a web browser
var config = {
port: 9005,
devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
paths: {
    html:  './src/*.html',
    dist: './dist'
}

};

gulp.task('connect', function(){  
  connect.server({
    root: '[dist]',
    port: config.port,
    base: config.devBaseUrl,
    livereload: true
  });
});


gulp.task('open',['connect'], function(){ 
  gulp.src('dist/index.html')
    .pipe(open({ url:config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/'}));
});

gulp.task('html',function(){      
  gulp.src(config.paths.html)
    .pipe(gulp.src(config.paths.dist))  
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'open', 'watch']);
```